# How to access to the javascript of a web page with python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web

I want to get the elements and use the functions in the javascript code of a web page with python.

For example, on [this site](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3304599A/en?q=core&num=100&oq=core), I want to be able to click 'previous result' or 'next result' that are above the html result page (right corner)

I've tried it using selenium, but I couldn't solve it yet... If someone can help me with this question, I'll be really appreciate of it.
Thanks!

Comment: paste the code you have and let us know whats not working

Comment: you don't need JS for this just use XPATH to find the <a> element... something like: //state-modifier[@id='nextResult']/a[@id='link']